# Spring Hibernate LazyInitializationException on @Transactional

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data, spring-transactions

I have a service that runs async task at startup that runs recursively:

```
@Service
public class TaskService {

    private final TaskRepository taskRepository;

    @Inject
    public TaskService(TaskRepository taskRepository) {
        this.taskRepository= taskRepository;
    }

    private final int currentTaskId = -1;

    @Transactional
    @PostConstruct
    private void init() {
        taskRepository.findByClosedDateIsNull().forEach(taskRepository::delete);
        runTask();
    }

    @Async
    @Transactional
    private void runTask() {
        if (!getCurrent().isPresent()) {
            Task task = new Task();
            //set props
            currentTaskId = taskRepository.save(task).getId(); 
        }
        Util.sleep(5000); //wrapper for simple Thread.sleep(long l).
        Task task = getCurrent().get();
        if (task.getEvents().size > 0) {
            //bussiness logic
            Util.sleep(1000);
        }
        runTask();
    }

    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    private Optional<Task> getCurrent() {
        return taskRepository.findOneById(currentTaskId).map(task -> {
            task.getEvents().size(); //throws the error here
            return task;
        });
    }

}
```

StackTrace:

> Caused by: org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: com.test.domain.Task.events, could not initialize proxy - no Session
>       at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.throwLazyInitializationException(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:576)
>       at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.withTemporarySessionIfNeeded(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:215)
>       at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.readSize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:156)
>       at org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentSet.size(PersistentSet.java:160)
>       at com.test.service.TaskService.lambda$getCurrent$5(TaskService.java:135)
>       at java.util.Optional.map(Optional.java:215)
>       at com.test.service.TaskService.getCurrent(TaskService.java:134)
>       at com.test.service.TaskService.runTask(TaskService.java:163)
>       at com.test.service.TaskService.init(TaskService.java:66)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleElement.invoke(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:365)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleMetadata.invokeInitMethods(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:310)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:133)
>       ... 21 common frames omitted

I also tried Hibernate.initialize(Object proxy);. OpenViewSessionFilter is not the solution for me. I don't want to set this collection EAGER.

Comment: Why is `OpenViewSessionFilter` not the solution? Can you use a fetch plan and make it eager for this query?

Comment: `OpenViewSessionFilter` decreases performance. + most of the methods like `getCurrent()` in other services works. I think the issue in the `@Async`, many `@Transactional` or recursive. I can't make it eager because I use JpaRepository. It cannot return eager collection if it's lazy. I'm trying to fetch collection in the `getCurrent()` method.

Comment: You're performing an explicit `sleep` in your handler. The overhead from the filter is **not** relevant.

Comment: Is it a way to `sleep` the method (maybe, Spring-way) to make it work? How can I deal without sleep?

Comment: First Spring uses proxies for things like transactions and async behavior. So basically your `@ASync` and `@Transactional` on the private method are useless (the method call doesn't pass through the proxy). Second there is no garantuee that the `@Transactional` on the `init` method is already applied (it might or might not be). Basically doing things like this in an `@PostConstruct` method isn't the right thing to do. Next to that you eventually will also run into a stack overflow from how you have setup your code right now. Calling `runTask` from `runTask` eventually breaks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution (don't know if it's a bad practice, but it works for me). Just create a default method in your JpaRepository and annotate it with @Transactional. In the service call this method.

Comment: Nice answer! The logic stays in the repository

Answer (score 0):

For me it solved the problem when I removed the `@Transactional` on the first function call (in your case this would be `init()`) and moved the `@Async` functionality to a separate bean.